# cytoscape.js not importing style

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I use cytoscape.js 2.7.5 to display a graph exported by Cytoscape Desktop as graph.cyjs converted to a Javascript file graph.js containing `"var graph = ... the content of the cyjs file ...;"`. With the following HTML I see the nodes and the edges but the style (colors, which attribute to use as node name) is not imported. How can I import the style as well?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script src="cytoscape.js"></script>
 <script src="graph.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="cy" style="width:100%;height:100vh;"></div>
  <script>
  var cy = cytoscape({
   container: document.getElementById('cy') // container to render in
  });
   cy.add(graph.elements);
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, Cytoscape Desktop doesn't save style information in its .csjs files so this has to be exported and imported separately:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script src="cytoscape.js"></script>
 <script src="graph.js"></script>
 <script src="style.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="cy" style="width:100%;height:100vh;"></div>
<script>
var cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),
    style: style[0].style
    });
cy.add(graph.elements);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```